# I cannot call the "server" method from the socket connection to receive messages on another function on KIVYMD

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, kivymd

I'am using KIVYMD to connect to a labview server that sends data to my local ipaddress,
I am using TextFields to connect to this server and it works, everytime i press the "Receive " button which is suposed to receive the data it just crashes with the

"msg = server.recv(1024)
NameError: name 'server' is not defined"

My python mainfile

```
import socket
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import socket
import threading
from kivy.clock import Clock

class CGuiApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

    def connect(self):
        try:
            address = self.root.ids.ip.text
            data = self.root.ids.port.text
            port = int(data)
            server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server.connect((address, port))
            print(f'Connected to {address, port}')
            return server
        except :
            print('Couldnt connect to server')

    def receive(self):
        msg = server.recv(1024)
        print(msg.decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CGuiApp().run()
    server = CGuiApp().connect()
```

MY Kv file

```
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 40

        MDTextField:
            hint_text: 'Ip'
            id: ip
            text:''

        MDTextField:
            hint_text: 'Port'
            id: port
            text:' 6486'

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Connect'
            on_release: app.connect()

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Receive'
            on_release: app.receive()

        MDLabel:
            id: label
            text: ''
```

Any help will be apreciated thanks!!

Comment: Your `server` is defined in the `connect()` method, but it is local to that method, so it is not defined in the `receive()` method. You can replace `server` by `self.server` to save it as an attribute of the `CGuiApp` instance.

Comment: That worked, thanks for taking the time and answering, i thought that by  adding 
server = CGuiApp().connect(), would make it like global for the class too,
but your method worked best
Also i cannot vote your answer as correct because you responded in a  comment and not in an actual answer box, have a nice day